# glassfish v3 starting slowly...?

Tags: glassfish

I am suffering from starting up  glassfish v3 .

it allways taking very long time to start the server. even not starts , all the time it will be idle.
I am trying to deploy ejb of about 160 .
It is not able to deploy all ejbs . for every restart it shows diff no of ejbs deployed.

what may be the problem.

console will be like this ..

```
[#|2011-09-30T15:13:19.718+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB CoManagerAccount : [com.wellzio.service.cus
tomer.ICoManagerAccount, com.wellzio.service.customer.ICoManagerAccount#com.well
zio.service.customer.ICoManagerAccount]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:19.828+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:22.171+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB TrialWap : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/TrialWap!com.we
llzio.service.customer.ITrialWap, java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/Trial
Wap]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:22.171+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB TrialWap : [com.wellzio.service.customer.IT
rialWap#com.wellzio.service.customer.ITrialWap, com.wellzio.service.customer.ITr
ialWap]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:22.296+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:24.156+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB States : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/States, java:glob
al/com.wellzio.service.customer/States!com.wellzio.service.customer.IStates]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:24.171+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB States : [com.wellzio.service.customer.ISta
tes, com.wellzio.service.customer.IStates#com.wellzio.service.customer.IStates]|
#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:24.281+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:25.656+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB PatientWapAssociation : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/Pa
tientWapAssociation, java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/PatientWapAssociat
ion!com.wellzio.service.customer.IPatientWapAssociation]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:25.656+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB PatientWapAssociation : [com.wellzio.servic
e.customer.IPatientWapAssociation, com.wellzio.service.customer.IPatientWapAssoc
iation#com.wellzio.service.customer.IPatientWapAssociation]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:25.765+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:29.250+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB WapAccount : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/WapAccount!co
m.wellzio.service.customer.IWapAccount, java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer
/WapAccount]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:29.250+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB WapAccount : [com.wellzio.service.customer.
IWapAccount, com.wellzio.service.customer.IWapAccount#com.wellzio.service.custom
er.IWapAccount]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:13:29.375+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:26:06.562+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.Gri
zzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(2);|service
exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:24
3)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java
:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java
:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(Container
Mapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:8
28)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFil
ter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultPro
tocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.jav
a:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.jav
a:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java
:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextT
ask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.
java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadP
ool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool
.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectionKeyHa
ndler$CloseHandler.notifyClosed(MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectionKeyHa
ndler$CloseHandler.remotlyClosed(MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.BaseSelectionKeyHandler.notifyRemotlyClose(BaseSelect
ionKeyHandler.java:233)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.notifyRemotelyClosed(OutputWriter.j
ava:353)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:148)

        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketCha
nnelOutputBuffer.java:326)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChan
nelOutputBuffer.java:398)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flush(SocketChannelOut
putBuffer.java:376)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.action(ProcessorTask.java:1247)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.action(Response.java:268)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputBuffer.doFlush(GrizzlyOutputB
uffer.java:434)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputBuffer.flush(GrizzlyOutputBuf
fer.java:405)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputStream.flush(GrizzlyOutputStr
eam.java:140)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:24
0)
        ... 17 more
|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:23:13.625+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.util
.Version|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(1);|Hibernate Validator
 4.1.0.Final|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:29:36.406+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.engi
ne.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=admin-thread-poo
l-4848(1);|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.J
PATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:29:36.656+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-39;|The Adm
in Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:29:36.656+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-39;|The Adm
in Console is starting. Please wait.|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:29:39.312+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB CustomerAuthentication : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/C
ustomerAuthentication!com.wellzio.service.customer.ICustomerAuthentication, java
:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/CustomerAuthentication]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:29:39.312+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB CustomerAuthentication : [com.wellzio.servi
ce.customer.ICustomerAuthentication#com.wellzio.service.customer.ICustomerAuthen
tication, com.wellzio.service.customer.ICustomerAuthentication]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:29:39.437+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:07.093+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB CreditCards : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/CreditCards,
 java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/CreditCards!com.wellzio.service.custom
er.ICreditCards]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:07.093+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB CreditCards : [com.wellzio.service.customer
.ICreditCards#com.wellzio.service.customer.ICreditCards, com.wellzio.service.cus
tomer.ICreditCards]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:07.203+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:08.671+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB TrialResponse : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/TrialRespo
nse, java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/TrialResponse!com.wellzio.service.
customer.ITrialResponse]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:08.671+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB TrialResponse : [com.wellzio.service.custom
er.ITrialResponse#com.wellzio.service.customer.ITrialResponse, com.wellzio.servi
ce.customer.ITrialResponse]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:08.796+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:09.687+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB TrialRoleTypes : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/TrialRole
Types, java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/TrialRoleTypes!com.wellzio.servi
ce.customer.ITrialRoleTypes]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:09.687+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB TrialRoleTypes : [com.wellzio.service.custo
mer.ITrialRoleTypes#com.wellzio.service.customer.ITrialRoleTypes, com.wellzio.se
rvice.customer.ITrialRoleTypes]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:09.812+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:10.828+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB TrialCustomerRoles : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/Trial
CustomerRoles, java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/TrialCustomerRoles!com.w
ellzio.service.customer.ITrialCustomerRoles]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:30:10.828+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB TrialCustomerRoles : [com.wellzio.service.c
ustomer.ITrialCustomerRoles, com.wellzio.service.customer.ITrialCustomerRoles#co
m.wellzio.service.customer.ITrialCustomerRoles]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:27.703+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:28.984+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB CustomerRoles : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/CustomerRo
les, java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/CustomerRoles!com.wellzio.service.
customer.ICustomerRoles]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:28.984+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB CustomerRoles : [com.wellzio.service.custom
er.ICustomerRoles#com.wellzio.service.customer.ICustomerRoles, com.wellzio.servi
ce.customer.ICustomerRoles]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:29.109+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:30.875+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB Trials : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/Trials, java:glob
al/com.wellzio.service.customer/Trials!com.wellzio.service.customer.ITrials]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:30.875+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB Trials : [com.wellzio.service.customer.ITri
als, com.wellzio.service.customer.ITrials#com.wellzio.service.customer.ITrials]|
#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:31.015+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:32.312+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Portable JNDI na
mes for EJB PhysicianAccount : [java:global/com.wellzio.service.customer/Physici
anAccount!com.wellzio.service.customer.IPhysicianAccount, java:global/com.wellzi
o.service.customer/PhysicianAccount]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:32.312+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Glassfish-specif
ic (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB PhysicianAccount : [com.wellzio.service.cus
tomer.IPhysicianAccount#com.wellzio.service.customer.IPhysicianAccount, com.well
zio.service.customer.IPhysicianAccount]|#]

[#|2011-09-30T15:32:32.468+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.t
ools.monitor.org.glassfish.admin.monitor|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|MNTG0201
:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monito
ring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later |#]
```

Comment: Could you resolve it ? :)